# Create a histogram in a cell based on condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

I need a histogram in a cell based on condition.

Example:
In:
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt09O.png)

My Out:
[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e18lo.png)

Needed Out:
[Needed Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKv2P.png)

So, If I'm using conditional formatting and choosing histogram, I have no option to choose the colour based on condition. My Output - this is what excel can suggest by basic tools. Needed Output - this is what I want to be suggested. Values < 0,85 - red histogram, < 0,95 - yellow, and < 1 - green.

Comment: Do you want this actually "in" the cell (e.g. a sparkline)? Or, simply aligned with a cell, but in a standard chart?

Comment: I want actually "in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a few steps. First, create a column with a non-percentage value of your value. In this case, I have that as column A.

Then select 100 columns to the right of your data (in this case, C3:CX11), and adjust the column width to 0.1 or 0.2.

Next, highlight that narrow column range (C3:CX11) and create 3 conditional format rules.

```
Green: =COLUMNS($C$2:C2)<=$A2

Yellow: =AND(COLUMNS($C$2:C2)<=$A2,$A2<90)

Red: =AND(COLUMNS($C$2:C2)<=$A2,$A2<80)
```

Adjust your cutpoints as needed, and rearrange if necessary, where Red runs first, then Yellow, then Green.
Done.

[image]

You can play around with border colors for visual effects.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot!